# How do I get a dazed Morty to recover?

Tags: pocket-mortys

I was wandering around the first portal after the Citadel of Ricks and was stingy with serum before fights. Now one of my Mortys is dazed.

[image: dazed Morty on the ice world]

I tried to heal him with Serum, but it says that I "can't restore health to a dazed Morty." [image: cant restore Morty image]

I imagine that the Heal Center would fix him up, but I can't seem to find a portal back to the citadel.

**How do I remove the dazed status from my Morty?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you can't. Salesman Rick's does not sell a revive item until after you battle Rick Prime in the Citadel of Ricks, and you can't get back to the Citadel to the healing center unless all of your Mortys become dazed.

After you battle Rick Prime (the first Rick you battle in the Citadel), Salesman Rick's sells Halzingers for 650 Schmeckles, which restore a dazed Morty to 50% HP. You can also craft Halzingers as well.

Alternatively, you can always just have your Mortys become dazed. There is no penalty for letting your Mortys die. Birdperson will take you back to the healing center for free. This is also useful if your Mortys are out of AP.

Comment: I don't believe there is a cash penalty for having all your Mortys become dazed, but I'm not certain

Comment: Guess i have some science to do.

Comment: I've confirmed that there is no cash penalty for all the mortys becoming dazed and Rick using the wubba lubba dub dub to return to the healing center.